# Git remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am trying to set up a git repo on my test server when I try to push from my windows computer

```
git push ssh://git@server.com:/path/.git
```

I get the error

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But when I ssh'd into my server and tried to do the the exact same command it worked just fine. Is this a problem with my git setup or with my windows setup

Comment: How do you SSH into the test server?

Comment: with `putty -ssh user@server.com`

Comment: And is the 'user' portion of that 'git'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be caused by a number of issues:

- Git is installed in some weird place on the server, *and* the environment that "git" user gets when being logged in interactively (you do this by hand via PuTTY or whatever) differs from the environment it gets when being logged in non-interactively (the git client does this for you).  This is because Unix shells read different startup files in these cases, and when `git` uses SSH to spawn remote `git` instance it still spawns the default (for the user) shell on the server.
- You have a local problem (say, you configured Git to use `plink.exe` to access the server, and it asks you to accept the host's key by entering "y" or "n" (which you can't do).

In any case, try these steps:

1. Run `plink.exe git@server.com "git --version"` and see it's able to run Git on the server at all.  If you don't use `plink.exe` use whatever binary is shipped with OpenSSH included with Git for Windows; probably it's `ssh.exe`.
2. Export `GIT_TRACE=1` before running `git push` and see if it prints out anything hinting at what went wrong, like this:

   ```
   C:\foo>GIT_TRACE=1
   C:\foo>git push ssh://git@server.com:/path/.git
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the GIT_TRACE hint. I had the exact same problem and it helped me see the request git was making.

I had the same issue and just resolved it by running the following command at the prompt:

> set GIT_SSH=

where the right side of = is no value.

Comment: @lonstar, another debugging "trick" is to use `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to make `libcurl`, which Git uses to implement accessing repositories using the `HTTP[S]` protocols, print out what it does -- analogous to passing the `--verbose` option to the `curl` binary. It might be used to trace authentication issues, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the user 'git' does not have write access to the remote repository, and that you may be connecting manually with your own username (cemurray, or some such).